# Is there any tool to convert a .NET 4.0 app to .NET 3.5 app?

Tags: .net

My current application is built with .NET 4.0 and it does have external references to Telerik control and few other controls.

I'd need to build my app with .NET 3.5 unfortunately... long story

Is there any tool to convert a .NET 4.0 app to .NET 3.5 app?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried to simply change the project settings in Visual Studio and run a build? Do you get any (compile) errors?

Comment: yes, tried that and got lots of errors; mainly complaining about Telerik control and some other features I'm using.

Comment: +1 for the "long story"...  I'm living that scenario lately too.

Answer (score 2):

if you change the properties of the application from 4.0 to 3.5 and build it will soon tell you any errors. There are lots of features of 4.0 that are not backwards compatible though so be warned

Answer (score 2):

The tool *is* Visual Studio (*and your smart programmer mind*).

1. On the **Project** menu, click *ProjectName* **Properties**.
2. Click the **Compile** tab.
3. Click **Advanced Compile Options**.
4. In the Target Framework (all configurations) list, select .NET Framework 3.5.
5. Click **OK**.
6. In the Target Framework Change message that appears, click **Yes**.

Finally, fix any errors that arise during the build process in case you are using something that relies on *.NET 4.0* and was not supported in *.NET 3.5*.

Comment: I know how to compile it in .NET 3.5; the question was about a convertor. I may have to find old versions of all the assemblies I'm using :(

Comment: I did the same thing you're doing and converted the Telerik project to Visual Studio 2008 (from 2010) because our company didn't use VS2010 yet, but unfortunately, you will have to unload (or comment out) A LOT of features in the new code because they simply won't work with .NET 3.5 because Telerik RadControls is a wrapper around ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit and many of the new features are only available in .NET 4.0.  It's fine to not use certain features since the upgrade won't require the new features.

Answer (score 0):

If you are downgrading assemblies referenced in your project(s), you will either need to go to the source where you downloaded the dll/assembly files and get the .NET 3.5 versions of the files OR download .NET reflector, modify the source code yourself and recompile the source code projects to the .NET 3.5 version. Then unreference the old dll files from your project(s) and re-reference the new dlls files.

I did the same thing you're doing and converted the Telerik project to Visual Studio 2008 (from 2010) because our company didn't use VS2010 yet, but unfortunately, you will have to unload (or comment out) A LOT of features in the new code because they simply won't work with .NET 3.5 because Telerik RadControls is a wrapper around ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit and many of the new features are only available in .NET 4.0. It's fine to not use certain features since the upgrade won't require the new features.

Converting the Telerik solution and projects from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2008 is the easy part.

In the *.sln file, change the Format..

```
old: Format Version 11.00
new: Format Version 10.00
```

In the *.sln file, change the Visual Studio version..

```
old: # Visual Studio 2010
new: # Visual Studio 2008
```

In the *.csproj files, update the .NET version "ToolsVersion" from "4.0" to "3.5" and also update any v10.0 occurrences to v9.0 if you find any.

Then start un-referencing the .NET 4.0 dll files and replace with .NET 3.5, and comment out any code you find that's broken.  If it's fixable, then fix it.